# one network two IIS web servers? will the switching occur?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-5

if

i have two IIS servers 5v on one network running winxp each hosting a separate site,

the navigation between the sites is related by using response.redirect("~/site2") when button is clicked on site1.

will this create any sort of chance of errors, like

you are connected to server1 which does not have this page!! or will the other IIS server read the browsers request and display the page?

it should but asking as i would like to know the downside of having two webservers on a single network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally use `response.redirect("~/site2")` then it will not navigate from one site to another.  ~/site2 will be interpreted as, site2 folder in the current web application.  You will need to use the absolute URL e.g. `response.redirect("http://xpmachine2/site2")`